# Will get shock from Isolated transformer?

Tags: transformer, safety

I have read a [good discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17496/how-is-using-a-transformer-for-isolation-safer-than-directly-connecting-to-the-p) about the safety of an isolated transformer.

However, in my understanding, the secondary side of the isolated transformer is floating, so will it has a high potential difference with the Earth ground? If it does, because I am at Earth potential, will I get shock when I touch the secondary side?

Answer (score 5):

The secondary of the transformer is floating, so it's not referenced to anything (a potential difference to earth ground does not exist). You will not get a shock if you touch one terminal. Touching both terminals, however, is not recommended, as a voltage exists across them.

Comment: Nice understatement at the end.